# CORS not working - 401

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Trying to fetch data from a WebApi. Here's the service call in TypeScript:

```
GetStatus(hostName: string): any {
    this.Http.post(this.ServiceBaseAddress)
        .success(data => {
            return data;
        });
}
```

On the server side, I have done the following to enable CORS:

1: Add NugetPackage `Microsoft.ASP.Net.Cors`

2: Add the EnableCors Attribute to one Controller (which I'm trying to call)

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class DeployController : ApiController
{ //...
}
```

3: Enable CORS in the WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
    config.EnableCors(); //...
```

4: Add custom Headers via Web.config (in the system.webServer region)

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I noticed that Fiddler seems to do some really nasty caching, which got me confused more than once...Now, at least, I get a response which has the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRGV2ZWxvcFxTUEFSQ1xEZXZlbG9wXFJ1bnRpbWVcU1BBUkMuTWFuYWdlbWVudEFwaVxNYW5hZ2VtZW50QXBpXGFwaVxkZXBsb3lcZ2V0aG9zdHM=?=
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 13:12:48 GMT
Content-Length: 6540
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

The content of the response is the 401 Error site of the service.

To get this working, I tried to add anonynous authentication to the WebApis Web.config, but without success:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Any Ideas what I could do? How do I authenticate?

---

**EDIT:** 
Turns out this is really an authentication Problem. The WebApi Authentication is set as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

- When I call the Webservice URI in IE or Chrome, I get the expected response.
- When I call it in Firefox and press cancel instead of entering my user credentials, I get the same Message that the http call from my website gets - 
  an issue with 401.2 Authentication Headers.

That being said, I need to know how to tell the angular Ajax call to use my credentials.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but this doesn't look like a CORS issue, you'd get a 405  Method Not Allowed if it were CORS. What happens if you call the WebAPI directly (e.g from Fiddler) seems to be the real problem, I would reframe the question.

Comment: try this; in your   <httpProtocol> you have to add <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" /> and any custom header with comma separated if you have and see if it works

Comment: @krish done, still get 401

Comment: @StephenByrne - you are right, it's not a CORS issue, please see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the answers given here plus some research, I found out what to do -
First, I had to modify the angular ajax call to pass my credentials like so:

```
this.Http.get(this.ServiceBaseAddress + addressPart, { withCredentials: true });
```

Then, as indicated by @michalczukm, I had to configure the service to accept those credentials.

As a cleanup, I moved all Cross-Origin-related stuff to `web.config` and removed the attributes

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:59664" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />        
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 1):

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Possible cases

- You don't have OPTIONS allowed without authentication. Hence `401` is returned on the OPTIONS query made to *check for cors*.
- CORS is working fine but your controller has a further layer of required authentication that you are not sending in the query (You should see a cookie like `.aspxauth` or Basic Auth)

Comment: seems you are right about the authentication, could you maybe check the edits?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you should add `SupportsCredentials` option.

In **asp.net 4**

```
configuration.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("https://mysite.mydomain.com", "*", "*") 
{
        SupportsCredentials = true 
});
```

That how it looks in **asp.net 5**

```
private static void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();

    var policy = new CorsPolicy();
    policy.Headers.Add("*");
    policy.Methods.Add("*");
    policy.Origins.Add("*");
    policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
    services.ConfigureCors(x => x.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicy, policy));
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely right, but unfortunately I missed to send the credentials on the client side, so this alone didn't have the desired effect.